# PHP change output depending how many variables exist

Tags: php, variables

Apologies if this is a simple question and/or it's nonsensical.

What I'm trying to do is change the output of a string, based on 2 simple variables.

This is the original variable;

```
$src = 'http://example.org';
```

And I have the following option variables which pull data from a Wordpress shortcode (If it exists);

```
$bg = $attr['background'];
$col = $attr['color'];
```

What I want to achieve is this, if neither of the option variables have values the original variable remains unchanged.

If only one of the option variables exist, the original variable's value becomes;

```
http://example.org?background='.$bg.'
```

or

```
http://example.org?color='.$col.'
```

Depending on which one has a value.

If both option variables have values, the original value needs to become;

```
http://example.org?background='.$bg.'&color='.$col.'
```

Can someone point me in the right direction on this please? It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$src = 'http://example.org';
$start = '?';

if(isset($attr['background'])) {
    $src .= $start . 'background=' . $attr['background'];
    $start = '&';
}

if(isset($attr['color'])) $src .= $start . 'col=' . $attr['color'];
```

Should be self-explanatory, but we slowly build up the $src variable depending on whether a background or color is set.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily using the [`add_query_arg()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/) function built into WordPress.

```
$url = 'http://example.org';

if ( isset($attr['background']) ) {

    add_query_arg( 'background', $attr['background'], $url );

}

if ( isset($attr['color']) ) {

    add_query_arg( 'color', $attr['color'], $url );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small function that creates the params out of a given parameter-array as you have it:

```
<?php
// the settings:
$attr = [];
$attr['background'] = "#ededed";
$attr['color'] = "red";
#$attr['otherparam'] = "123456";
$url = 'http://example.org';

// the method
function createParamsString($params) {
    $p = [];
    foreach($params as $key=>$value) { 
       $p[]  = $key."=".urlencode($value);
    }
    return implode("&", $p);
}

// usage:
$paramsString = createParamsString($attr);

$url = !empty($paramsString) ? $url."?".$paramsString : $url;

echo $url;
```

This way it's modular. You can just add entries to `$attr` an all is good. `urlencode` is important if you have a values like `#EDEDED` for background.